# get a specific column from a custom Adapter

Tags: android, database, onitemclicklistener, custom-adapter

I did a query in a database and return it inside a list that i  put on a custom adapter and then i put in a listview.
Works fine until i use the onItemClikListener. I want to get the column "_id" from the query and i don't know how to do it (i want to pass this id as parameter for another activity).
I tried getItemId from my custom adapter but it returns the position on the list, not the column "_id".
Ex.: my query select * where name = x; return rows with id 1 and 3...but the getItemId make it position 1="_id1" and 2="_id3"...and when i pass it no another activity the query returns the rows with  the "_id" 1 and 2;

```
//Here i get the item position and pass to another activity
listagem.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long id) {    
    String Column_id = String.valueOf(adapter.getItemId(position));
    Intent mostraLetra = new Intent(musica.this.getActivity(), ExibeMusica.class);
    mostraLetra.putExtra("id", Column_id);
    startActivity(mostraLetra);
    }
});

//Here i pass the Id when i click on a item on the list
public String[] exibeMusica(String idMusica){
    String r = idMusica;
    String[] resultado = {};
    Cursor resul = bancodados.query(Tabela_musica, new String[] {"_id", "Musica","Cantor","letra_musica","cat_oracao","cat_missa"}, "_Id = " +r+"", null, null, null, null, null);
    resul.moveToFirst();
    resultado[0] = String.valueOf(resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("_id")));
    resultado[1] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("Musica"));
    resultado[2] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("Cantor"));
    resultado[3] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("letra_musica"));
    resultado[4] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("cat_oracao"));
    resultado[5] = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("cat_missa"));
    resul.close();
    return resultado;
}

//This is my custom adapter
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

LayoutInflater inflater;
List<musica.ItemLista> itens;

public CustomAdapter(Activity a, List<musica.ItemLista> itens) {
    super();    
    this.itens = itens;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)a.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return itens.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    musica.ItemLista item = itens.get(position);
    View vi = convertView;

    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha_listview, null);
        TextView id = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.linhaLista.id);
        TextView musica = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.linhaLista.musica);
        TextView artista = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.linhaLista.cantor);
        ImageView oracao = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.linhaLista.cat_oracao);
        ImageView missa = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.linhaLista.cat_missa);
        id.setText(String.valueOf(item.id));
        musica.setText(item.musica);
        artista.setText(item.cantor);
        String imgOra = item.oracao;
        String imgMissa = item.missa;

        if (imgOra.equals(null)) {
            oracao.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
        }else if(imgOra.equals("louvor")) {
            oracao.setImageResource(R.drawable.louvor);
        }else if(imgOra.equals("adoracao")) {
            oracao.setImageResource(R.drawable.adoracao);
        }

        if (imgMissa.equals(null)) {
            missa.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
        }else if(imgOra.equals("louvor")) {
            missa.setImageResource(R.drawable.louvor);
        }else if(imgOra.equals("adoracao")) {
            missa.setImageResource(R.drawable.adoracao);
        }
    }return vi;
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me to get the correct "_id" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set tag to the row view in `getView` of the adapter like this

```
    .........
    }
    vi.setTag(String.valueOf(item.id))
    return vi;
    .........
```

and then

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long id) {    
String Column_id = (String) arg1.getTag();
......
```

Comment: Wow...this saved my project...thanks Naeem...one day i'll be good as you..hehehe...thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

While setting the linha_listview.xml in your CustomAdapter, you try to add one more textview to the linha_listview.xml like below:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/pid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

As you set this visibility to gone, it is no more visible on the listview. Later you set this textview by pidtextview.setText(column_id) in your getView() method. So, while clicking on the list item, get this column_id by

```
String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();
```

in your list item listener. By this above code, you would get the pid, Pass this to the other activity through intent.putExtra(); In that activity retrieve the data from getIntent() and retrieve the data of that particular row which contains that column_id and display that particular row details on that activity. Hope this helps. If you still get any doubts, get back.

Answer (score 0):

write this code in onItemClickListner

resul.moveToPosition (position)

String Column_id  = resul.getString(resul.getColumnIndex("_id");